# How to config not_analyzed with @Field annotation in spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.0.RC2

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

In spring-data-elasticsearch 3.0.0.RC2, @Field annotation has a boolean index() and a String analyzer(). 
How to config "not_analyzed" with @Field annotation?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

With previous versions of Spring Data ES that worked with ES 2.x, you used to do it this way:

```
@Field(type=FieldType.String, index=FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
String myField;
```

With Spring Data ES 3.0.0 (which works with ES 5.x), you now do it like this:

```
@Field(type=FieldType.Keyword)
String myField;
```

Comment: How to proceed if the attribute is @Field(type=FieldType.Object) and ES 7.x?

Comment: @val so, we cannot control index type ? say index=not_analyzed as we could in ES

Comment: @LasitPant `index=not_analyzed` has been deprecated in ES5, so if you're using a recent release then it is not necessary anymore